# Complex Electric Flux Integral

Tags: complex-analysis, electromagnetism

I am working through Gamelin and am having trouble understanding the following:

> The electric field is given by $\textbf{E} = \frac{1}{r} e_r$ where $e_r$ is the unit radial vector. Through each circle $\lbrace |z| = r \rbrace$ there is a positive outward flux given by $$\int_{|z| = r} \textbf{E} \cdot \textbf{n} \, ds = \int_{|z| = r} \textbf{E} \cdot e_r \, ds = \int_0^{2\pi} d \theta = 2 \pi.$$

I am confused on the second to last equalities. I believe Gamelin is skipping some steps and I don't quite understand how to translate between $ds$, $dr$ and $d\theta$.

Comment: $ds= r d \theta$, try drawing out a circle of radius $r$ in the Cartesian plane. The differential line element is $ds$, then switch to polar coordinates.

Comment: I see now, $ds = dr + r d\theta$, but $r$ is constant on $|z| = r$, so we have $ds = r d\theta$. Thank you